# .htaccess & mod_rewrite

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have the following:

```
RewriteRule  ^(.*)/(.*)\.php?$ index.php?city=$1 [L]
```

It catches for: mysite.com/salt-lake-city/file.php

I want it to also catch for: mysite.com/salt-lake-city/ and forward to: index.php?cit=salt-lake-city. I've tried to add:

```
RewriteRule  ^(.*)/?$ index.php?city=$1 [L]
```

However, this ends up forwarding to index.php?city=index.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteRule  ^(.*)/(.*\.php)?$ index.php?city=$1 [L]
```